# Method for SELECT in java: what to return and how to close resources?

Tags: java, resultset, cachedrowset

I am new to Java. I'm trying to create a class containing some utility methods for SQL operations in Java 1.6 to be used for general purposes.

I have written down a `selectMethod` for getting the results of a `SELECT` on the DB.

**Problem**: if my `selectMethod` method returns a `ResultSet` type, then when I call the method its related resources (`ResultSet`, `Statement`) will unavoidably remain open: I cannot close them from another method because they have been created into the `selectMethod`... on the other hand I cannot close them inside the `selectMethod`, otherwise the latter wouldn't return anything.

So my point is:
==> How can I close the resources? <==

I cannot use the `try-with-resource` because I'm using an earlier version of Java.

Among similar questions I haven't found a "general way" to overcome this issue.

**Solutions**: The only two ways I know at the moment:

**A)** avoid creating a `selectMethod` that returns a `ResultSet` type, and only create a method in which the query is performed internally, together with other operations on the query results. Then close all the resources into the method.

Example:

```
public String selectMethod(String query, Connection conn) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    String myOutput = "";
    try {
        stmt = conn.PreparedStatement(query);
        rset = st.executeQuery();
        myOutput = rs.getString(2);   // the "particular task" I perform on the data retrieved
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    return myOutput;
}
...
...
// method call:
String myQuery = "SELECT colA FROM table_name WHERE table_id = 192837465";
String theDataINeeded = selectMethod(myQuery, myConn);
myConn.close();
```

Drawbacks of A): I wanted a SQL class of general use and not limited to a particular task...

**B)** into the `selectMethod`, copying the `ResultSet` data into a `CachedRowSet` and return the `CachedRowSet`.

Example:

```
public CachedRowSet selectMethod(String query, Connection conn) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    CachedRowSetImpl crset = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.PreparedStatement(query);
        rset = st.executeQuery();
        crset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crset.populate(rset);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    return crset;
}
...
...
// method call:
String myQuery = "SELECT colA FROM table_name WHERE table_id = 192837465";
CachedRowSetImpl theDataINeeded = new CachedRowSetImpl();
theDataINeeded = selectMethod(myQuery, myConn);
myConn.close();
```

Drawabacks of B): I am afraid of running out of memory when doing select with many rows. I cannot make a *query with pagination* with `LIMIT... OFFSET...` because my DB version is below Oracle 12g, and I don't want to make query manipulations to insert `row_number() between ... and ...`. I'd like my utility to work with any kind of query.

Does anyone know other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider reading about _ORM_ tools like Hibernate, which can let you interact with your database by working with _objects_, instead of clunky statements as you are doing above.

Comment: I am sorry for annoying you with my *clunky statements*, as I said I am new to Java. Thanks for the advice btw.

Comment: My rule of thumb is "don't close what's not yours". So in your method, statement and result set are "yours", but the connection is not - it was given to you as a parameter, so it technically isn't your method's responsibility to close it - that should be done by whoever created the connection initially.

Comment: thank you :) I edited the question deleting the connection close.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be providing result mapper to the method like below;

```java
public interface ResultMapper<T> {

    /**
     * Extract row from the columns of the {@link ResultSet}.
     * Implementors should just get the values for the columns and not call {@link ResultSet#next()} or {@link ResultSet#close()}
     *
     * @param rs the rs
     * @return the t
     */
    T extractRow(ResultSet rs);
}

//
// see ResultMapper
// Be aware that this method returns list of type <T>
public <T> List<T> selectMethod(final String query, final Connection conn, final ResultMapper<T> resultMapper) {
        final List<T> results = new LinkedList<>();

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        try {

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rset.next()) {
                results.add(resultMapper.extractRow(rset));
            }
            return results;
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            // handle sql exceprion
        } finally {
            try {
                rset.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                // log error while closing
            }
        }
        
        return results;
    }
```

Since you are new to Java, you may need to take a look at [java generics](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics) and

So, based on the example you provided, we want to extract String field. You can define your result mapper like this:

```java
public class MyResultMapper implements ResultMapper<String> {
    @Override
    public String extractRow(final ResultSet rs) {
        return rs.getString(2);   // the "particular task" I perform on the data retrieved
    }
}
```

Then you can just execute query like this:

```java
String output = SqlUtils.selectMethod(sql, conn, new MyResultMapper()).stream()
                .findFirst();
```

Comment: `findFirst()` in the very last line is useless from memory consumption point of view. The way you've done implementation inside `selectMethod` means that the app will first load all results from database and consume all the memory from that, and then it's just going to throw away everything in the result list to return first element of it.

Comment: I know this is not efficient in this use case. Also, `selectMethod` does not necessarily have to return `List<T>` either. But, thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: I'm speaking to this line of the OP: "Drawabacks of B): I am afraid of running out of memory when doing select with many rows". Realizing full actual list is going to get the app to select many rows.

Comment: I did not understand? You'll be already have full control what needs to be done with `ResultSet` in `ResultMapper`. You may consume all result set or even not at all...

Comment: Many thanks to Ali Can for the answer. Unfortunately I don't think that's a good way: as Prokhorov pointed out, the method will load all the results in memory and then throw away those not needed... The case with the string was only an example, what if I want to do a ```SELECT * from TABLE```?

Comment: Ahh ok, I understood the performance considerations now. I see you are not able to use `LIMIT ... OFFSET`, but what about `CURSOR` usage ? Or, you can use ORM library (such Hibernate) as others already stated :)

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a `Result` object that implements `AutoClosable` (or `Closable` – I don't remember when these were introduced to Java)?

The `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects are attributes to that `Result` instance, and your `selectMethod()` is just the factory for it. Then you can do it like this:

```
Connection connection = …
Result result = null;
String query = "…";
try
{
     result = selectMethod( query, connection );
     ResultSet resultSet = result.getResultSet();
     myOutput = resultSet.getString(2);   // the "particular task" I perform on the data retrieved
}
catch( …Exception e )
{
    // Handle the exception
    …
}
finally
{
    if( result != null ) result.close();
}
```

The class `Result` will roughly look like this:

```
public final class Result implements Closeable
{
    private final Statement m_Statement;
    private final ResultSet m_ResultSet;

    public Result( final Statement statement, final ResultSet resultSet )
    {
        m_Statement = statement;
        m_ResultSet = resultSet;
    }

    public final ResultSet getResultSet() { return m_ResultSet; }

    @Override
    public final void close() throws SQLException
    {
        m_ResultSet.close();
        m_Statement.close();
    }
}
```

Of course, my error handling is poor and needs improvement …

`connection` is not yours, and you may not close it …

And `resultSet` (that one inside the `try-catch-finally` block) is just a copy to the reference that is hold by `m_ResultSet`, inside the `Result` instance. Therefore, a call to `resultSet.close()` is redundant (or obsolete – or even dangerous with my poor error handling).

And your `selectMethod()` looks like this:

```
public final Result selectMethod( String query, Connection connection ) throws SQLException
{
    Statement statement = connection.PreparedStatement( query );
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    return new Result( statement, resultSet );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! At the end I followed your way, more or less. I don't know how to implement AutoCloseable or Closeable... I explain what I did in my own answer (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the answer of tquadrat, I find another way to close the resources by just defining attributes in the class `SQLUtil`:

```
public class SQLUtil {
    
    //attributes:
    Connection connection;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    Statement statement;

    public void connectToMyDB {
        // populate the connection attribute
        ...
    }
    
    public ResultSet selectMethod (String query) {
        // here I populate the statement and resultSet attribute
        ...
        return resultSet;
    }
    
    ...
    public void cleanUpRes () {
        if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
        if (statement != null) resultSet.close();
    }
}
```

Then, when I will call the `selectMethod` I will get the `resultSet` without storing it in memory. After processing it, I will close it by calling `cleanUpRes()`.

Drawbacks I see:

1 - there is only one `resultSet` related to the `SQLUtil` object, so if I would have to handle two or more queries together, I'd have to instantiate many different `SQLUtil` objects... Maybe using an array of `resultSet` attributes could work instead of only one? Btw this is beyond the scope of the question :)

2 - The external method is responsible for closing the resources

What do you think? Thanks everybody

Comment: I added some more flesh to my answer so it would be easier to understand what I originally meant.